# How to join 2 tables based on a like in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 tables Employee and Company_Employee.

Employee: 
ID, FirstName

Company_Employee:
ID, Company_ID, Employee_ID

I want to do a search by First Name. I was thinking my query would look like:

```
   select FirstName, ID from Employee where FirstName LIKE '%John%' and ID in (select id from Company_Employee)
```

This query returns no rows.  Does anyone know how I can get the rows with a like by FirstName with these 2 tables?

Thanks!

Comment: You've used the id field from Company_Employee - shouldn't you have used Employee_ID (inside the brackets)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query compares a company_employee.id with an employee.id.  It should probably compare employee.id with company_employee.**employee_id**.

You can rewrite the query more clearly with a join:

```
select *
from employee e
join company_employee ce
    on e.id = ce.Employee_ID
where e.FirstName like '%John%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT
*
FROM
Employee e
INNER JOIN Company_Employee ce JOIN ON e.Id = ce.Id)
WHERE 
FirstName LIKE '%JOHN%'
```